# Maven doesn't use repository specified in the pom.xml of dependency

Tags: java, maven, jboss, drools

Our project depends on drools

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven can find `drools-compiler` in Maven central repository. The problem is that Maven cannot find some dependencies of `drools-compiler`, which are located in jboss Maven repository http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/.

The parent of `drools-compiler` is `drools-multiproject`, and it declares jboss repository as follows

```
<repository>
  <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
  <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

I also checked the effective pom of `drools-compiler`, and found jboss maven repository is listed.

In theory Maven should use jboss Maven repository to search those dependencies, but sometimes it doesn't.

I don't know whether there other settings affect Maven's behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed your settings.xml ? Do you use a repository manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the dependent repository in your POM. Adding dependent repositories transitively is a potential security bug, so probably Maven is using only repositories listed in your POM.

Comment: Maven can find those dependencies in my develping evironment without any changes. But in other people's develping environemnt, it can't. As you said, we need to add jboss repository explictly in their environments. It's very strange, and I want to know whether there are other settings related.

Comment: When artifacts are found in your local repository, Maven does not try to download them unless you force the update. You can also add the repository inside the POM, without the need to add the repository in the settings of each machine.